# Wii Virtual Console -- Black screen

Tags: nintendo-wii, virtual-console, super-mario-bros

[According to Nintendo](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2890/~/display-problems-while-playing-virtual-console-games), when you get a black screen playing Virtual Console games, you can fix it by pressing Z+A+2 on the "Operations Manual" screen.

However, I don't have a Wii Nunchuck, only a Classic Controller. Can I perform this task using these controllers?

Comment: Note that these instructions are for when a game consistently gives you a black screen every time you try to play it. If the games works normally most of the time but you occasionally get a black screen then your game is crashing (or maybe you have a bad cable) and these instructions won't help.

Comment: I have a black screen 100% of the time. It's definitely the issue described here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you can only do this with the Nunchuck controller. Agh.